# In windows 7 inetmgr command is giving Error

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-7

I am trying to setup my asp website in windows 7. I installed  that from  turn windows feature on or off. which is there in control panel program and features. I installed first time. I set upped Physical path to E:\myfolder. Then i come to know that i forgot to install asp. So I unchecked that Internet information service and given ok. that time its asked for restart the system. I given restart later. Then again checked and and installed. That time i am unable to run my application. Then i closed IIS manager and restarted my system. Now if i give inetmgr in run it is giving error "Windows cannot find inetmgr. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again". So i thought IIS is not properly installed then again i uninstalled and installed. But Not working giving same error... can any one tell me how to solve this problem.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually whenever you turn windows features on/off you must have to restart the  system....otherwise the changes will not reflect properly...

As per above description....

1.you installed iis and then uninstalled....

2.After installing .net you haven't restarted that system and you have installed the IIS(The previous uninstall state will be exists until unless you restart the system)

So, Solution is

1. Restart the system..try Start -> run -> inetmgr

if IIS is started it is properly installed...if it is not opened and if it gives the above error then go to enable windows features on(i mean install IIS then)....

The only solution is proper restrart after doing any change....

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you have installed IIS properly on your machine and also check that inetmgr.exe file is exist in  C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv.